# android architecture navigation OnNavigatedListener with backstack

Tags: android, navigation, listener, android-architecture-navigation

I would like to use [NavController.OnNavigatedListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/navigation/NavController.OnNavigatedListener) to log destinations changing events. The problem is that when some fragment is saved in backstack than for every navigation change is `onNavigated` called ones more and destination is that fragment which is saved in backstack. I need to filter this events, but I don't know how. I was trying to find something usefull in `destination` but I found nothing.

```
class MyOnNavigatedListener() : NavController.OnNavigatedListener {

override fun onNavigated(controller: NavController, destination: NavDestination) {
//log events
}
```

}

Comment: `onNavigated()` is called whenever the destination changes, be it because it is due to a `navigate()` call or from a `popBackStack()` call. Are you saying you want to filter out the events caused by `popBackStack()` like calls?

Comment: I don't think so. In my case `onNavigate()` is called twice when destination changes. Once with right destination and once with destination which is fragment inside backstack and that second call is what I want to eliminate or filter.

Comment: If that's the case, please [file a bug](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=409828&template=1093757) with a sample project that reproduces your issue as that is certainly not expected.

Comment: @RadekŠpinka can you provide your full code, especially how you navigating between destinations

Answer (score 1):

in AndroidX

`NavController.OnNavigatedListener` -> `NavController.OnDestinationChangedListener`